# How to convert array data to object in react js?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I want to convert below data

```
[[size:'l',color:'red'],[size:'xl',color:'blue']]
```

to

```
[{size:'l',color:'red'},{size:'xl',color:'blue'}]
```

in react js

plz help me to fix it. Thank you in advance

Comment: Convert to invalid js? Ther is no such syntax.

Comment: In the first place, there is no such thing as [a:1, b:2] inside array in Javascript. You get exception first before you can even ask question in here. Secondly this has nothing to do with ReactJs.. this is more about plain javascript. See here for more understanding about array - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: do you mean the first data `[[size:'l',color:'red'],[size:'xl',color:'blue']]` is of type string?

Answer (score 0):

First of all , your data is an invalid js structure , 
If you use the last invalid data as string then , at first all key and values should be strings , apply replace you could reach that result by using below snippet

(remove brackets by curly braces except first and last )

```js
let arrayString = '[["size":"l","color":"red"],["size":"xl","color":"blue"]]';

let regexLeft  = /(?!^)(\[)(?!$)/g;
let regexRight = /(?!^)(\])(?!$)/g;
let newArray = arrayString.replace( regexLeft, '{' );
newArray = newArray.replace( regexRight, '}' );
let object = JSON.parse(newArray);

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look below:

```js
const arrayToObject = (array, key) => {
  const defaultValue = {};
  return array.reduce((obj, item) => {
    return {
      ...obj,
      [item[key]]: item,
    };
  }, defaultValue);
};

console.log('Data: ', arrayToObject);
```

I hope it would help you out.